# App icon in dock is wrong

Tags: icons, launcher, dock, png

When I start some 3rd party apps from search bar they show on the dock but with a substitute icon image "ubuntu settings wheel". I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.10. They both have the same problems. How can I set this icon?[image: screenshot of dock. These two icons show the same app, how to make them look the same?]